# Cannot connect cassandra with java

Tags: java, cassandra, cql

I am trying to connect cassandra with JAVA. Added following libraries:
apache-cassandra-cql-1.0.3.jar
apache-cassandra-thrift-3.6.0.jar
libthrift-0.9.2.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar
slf4j-simple-1.7.21.jar

Here is my code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Connection con = null;
        try {

            Class.forName("org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver");
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver());

          //  con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9042/key_space");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:cassandra:root/root@localhost:9042/key_space");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

When I used first connection string, it gave me the following error:

```
Error: String index out of range: -1
```

However, for the second connection string. This error occurred:

```
org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.DriverResolverException: Read a negative frame size (-2080374784)
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
stack trace: org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.DriverResolverException: Read a negative frame size (-2080374784)!
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraConnection.<init>(CassandraConnection.java:91)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver.connect(CassandraDriver.java:86)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

Where am I going wrong? Kindly assist me.

Comment: Provide stack trace.

Comment: Question edited, please have a look

Comment: Cassandra does not use SQL, and I am not sure that its CQL is like SQL enough for use via JDBC.  Instead, I would highly recommend that you look into use a different Cassandra driver, such as DataStax' [Java driver](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.0/java-driver/whatsNew2.html).

Comment: what version of C* are you using? those libs are for an ancient version. +1 what Castaglia said, you should use the java driver https://github.com/datastax/java-driver.

Comment: Actually I am trying to integrate solr and cassandra. And for that I have to get a connection string for solrconfig.xml and data-config.xml. Therefore, I used this method to get connection string in order to be sure that there is no flaw with the connection string.

Comment: A somewhat wild guess but you're importing Thrift dependencies but connecting to the native port (9042). Can you try the Thrift port (9160) instead? Also some info about the server side C* version would be helpful.

Comment: I don't understand what C* version you are talking about. I changed the port in the connection url but no luck. This error occur: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed. I have asked this question separately, please have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38334952/error-while-connecting-to-cassandra-through-solr